# Can you set a top layer to be unselectable such that objects under it are still selectable?

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape, I'd like to trace a bitmap image. However, whichever part of it I trace first occludes the rest of the imported bitmap, making this a cumbersome process of lowering and raising the bitmap out of the way. Eventually, some path or shape gets trapped underneath another and moving those out of the way is never really an option because I'll never be able to line them up again afterward.

It would be convenient to be able to set the bitmap into its own layer, and make that layer on top (so that it's never occluded) and opacity 50%. I can still draw on the layer underneath with this, making tracing those out easier.

However, as soon as I finish with the path tool, that object is no longer selectable. I can't make adjustments (to the bezier handles, etc). And it's often difficult to get it perfect on the first try.

Is there a setting that can make a layer non-interactive?